# Read more & Read less in website page content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Expected output: i want Read more & Read less click option be at the bottom with all content which include paragraph & list.. (Codepen shows Read more & Read less click option at the top)
[image]
Here what i tried:
HTML

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read More</a>
<div class="content">Testing
  <ul>
    <li>first</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".content").hide();
  $(".show_hide").on("click", function () {
    var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'Read More' : 'Read Less';
    $(".show_hide").text(txt);
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

Codepen link for Read more & read less implementation:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/Shahbazmak/pen/gOPWwbY)

Answer (score 2):

To move Read More link to the bottom and have it work use "prev" instead of "next" method.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".show_hide").on("click", function () {
        var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'Read More' : 'Read Less';
        $(".show_hide").text(txt);
        $(this).prev('.content').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Testing
<ul>
<li>first</li>
</ul>

</div>
<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read More</a>
```

Comment: you have also moved a the `a` tag after the `div` end. The OP wants to have it at the top. This is NOT a complete solution according to the question asked.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysHelping you are incorrect, OP stated: "i want Read more & Read less click option be at the bottom" and I have put the link at the bottom.

Comment: Hi all i wanted to highlight is that the OP could have moved from top to bottom by himself. He wants keep the a tag at the bottom but on click move it to to bottom which is very tricky.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping OP wants the link at the bottom and for it to open and close the read more section, the point here is how to get the JavaScript/jQuery to work, not how to move the link.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".show_hide").on("click", function () {     
    var txt = $(".content").hasClass('visible') ? 'Read More' : 'Read Less';
    $(".show_hide").text(txt);
    $(".content").toggleClass("visible");
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  height:90px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.content.visible {
  height:auto;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Testing
  <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>first</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for this

```
.show_hide{
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
}
```

Or just put it at the bottom of a container that is what people do

Comment: The selector is next so when the link is at the bottom the selector is no longer valid; needs to be "prev".

Answer (score 0):

Your `content` class (which gets shown and hidden) contains all of your visible content. You just need to **include some content that does not have the `content` class before your `a` element**, something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
  $(".show_hide").on("click", function() {
    var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'Read More' : 'Read Less';
    $(".show_hide").text(txt);
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Always shown</h3>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Read More</a>
<div class="content">
  <h3>Sometimes shown</h3>
  <p>More text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is NOT a solution according to the question asked. Please refer to the question asked. Thanks

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I see what you're saying. I interpreted the OP's phrase "at the bottom" to mean "at the bottom of the default visible content", which is a common use case on the Web. But  perhaps the OP did intend the phrase more literally as you suggest.